# How to create a List of Lists and add Lists of any type ti this one in Java?

Tags: java, list

I would like to know how to create a List that can contain others Lists, which may themselves contain any type of object.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
List<List<Object>> lists;// Also tried this List<List<? extends Object>> listados;
    List<Integer> code;
    List<String> name;
    lists.add(1, code);
    lists.add(2, name);
```

Comment: Did you instantiate list before `add`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way too,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(1);
l.add(2);

ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
l1.add("hi");
l1.add("hello");

lists.add(l);
lists.add(l1);

for(ArrayList al : lists){

    for(Object o : al){
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hardly think using a raw type to bypass generics answers the question

Comment: Could you please explain me the advantages of use an ArrayList?

Comment: @NonExistent there is no advantage of using this way, it is better to [program to interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
    List<List<? extends Animal>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Person> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
    listOne.add(new Person("abc"));
    listOne.add(new Person("def"));

    List<Dog> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    listTwo.add(new Dog("abc"));
    listTwo.add(new Dog("def"));

    lists.add(listOne);
    lists.add(listTwo);
```

Comment: Nou, you only add Lists of the same type, what i need is to add lists of different types to a single List.

Comment: You mean something like this (see update)

Comment: Mmm, yeah something like that, but if you can do it with real classes i'll be thankful

Comment: these are real classes

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is basically correct.  I'll just modify it slightly.

```
List<List<Object>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

List<Integer> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
listOne.add(1);
listOne.add(2);

List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
listTwo.add("three");
listTwo.add("four");

lists.add(listOne);
lists.add(listTwo);
```

Comment: Allowing `Object` is not tighter typed practice, you should restrict type as much as you can

Comment: For the first line, can you do it like this: List<List<? extends Object>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: It doesn't even compile. Test.java:16: error: no suitable method found for add(List<Integer>)
lists.add(listOne);

Comment: It doesn't work for me...

Comment: Change `List<List<Object>>` to `List<List<? extends Object>>`

Comment: @TNT you're right, but if i do that i get an error, how will i convert a value to (`? extends Object`) for example if i wnat to add something to a string: `for(int i=1;i<lists.size();i++){lists.get(i).add("File #"+i);}` ?

Comment: @NonExistent I suggest posting a new question for that. It would be more beneficial for you and everyone else here on SO.